How to compare AVPlayerItem
I'm new to swift.
This is a code from this sample becoming_a_now_playable_app, at AssetPlayer's handlePlayerItemChange() method.
guard let currentIndex = playerItems.firstIndex(where: { $0 == currentItem }) else { return } 

At here, playerItems is an array of AVPlayerItem, and currentItem is AVPlayerItem.
I can't understand how this code works. How isEqual() possible for AVPlayerItem? I can't find any overrided methods like isEqual() or hash() at AVPlayerItem.

In swift you enable the == operator by making your objects conform to the Equatable protocol (and implementing the == operator.) I don't see Equatable conformance for AVPlayerItem, so I'm not sure.

Search on Equatable in the Xcode docs. They show an example of adding Equatable conformance to a class StreetAddress. (Your type needs to implement a static func ==.)

For NSObject-subclasses, the default implementation of == calls  isEqual(to:) which checks for pointer equality. In Swift, this is equivalent to ===. So any two NSObjects are equal if they are the same object, which is what is happening here.

I guess I knew that at some point, but had forgotten. Thanks. (I'm getting out of practice with NSObjects. Scary, considering how much Objective-C I've written in years past!)

I'd be inclined to write that comparison using === to make it crystal clear that I was comparing for pointer equality.
